kdb q functional select variable as symbol or not
With the following:
q)t:([] e:1 2 3 4 5 6; a:0 0 1 2 3 4; b: 1 2 0 0 3 4; c:1 2 3 4 0 1)

q)t
e a b c
-------
1 0 1 1
2 0 2 2
3 1 0 3
4 2 0 4
5 3 3 0
6 4 4 1

q)colist: `a`b`c

q)colist
`a`b`c

Functional select using value:
q)?[`t; enlist(any;(enlist,value (each;{(=;x;0)};colist))); 0b; ()]
e a b c
-------
1 0 1 1
2 0 2 2
3 1 0 3
4 2 0 4
5 3 3 0

value select fails with symbolic version of colist:
q)?[`t; enlist(any;(enlist,value (each;{(=;x;0)};`colist))); 0b; ()]
'type
  [0]  ?[`t; enlist(any;(enlist,value (each;{(=;x;0)};`colist))); 0b; ()]
       ^

eval version of query works with symbolic version of colist:
q)?[`t; enlist(any;(enlist,eval (each;{(=;x;0)};`colist))); 0b; ()]
e a b c
-------
1 0 1 1
2 0 2 2
3 1 0 3
4 2 0 4
5 3 3 0

But the non-symbolic version of colist fails with eval:
q)?[`t; enlist(any;(enlist,eval (each;{(=;x;0)};colist))); 0b; ()]
'c
  [0]  ?[`t; enlist(any;(enlist,eval (each;{(=;x;0)};colist))); 0b; ()]
                                ^

The k version of each, k){x'y}, works in quotes with value:
q)?[`t; enlist(any;(enlist,value ("k){x'y}";{(=;x;0)};colist))); 0b; ()]
e a b c
-------
1 0 1 1
2 0 2 2
3 1 0 3
4 2 0 4
5 3 3 0

But not with the eval version:
q)?[`t; enlist(any;(enlist,eval ("k){x'y}";{(=;x;0)};`colist))); 0b; ()]
'type
  [0]  ?[`t; enlist(any;(enlist,eval ("k){x'y}";{(=;x;0)};`colist))); 0b; ()]
                                ^

Functional query generall doesn't work without the value or eval:

q)?[`t; enlist(any;(enlist,(each; {(=;x;0)};`colist))); 0b; ()]
'type
  [0]  ?[`t; enlist(any;(enlist,(each; {(=;x;0)};`colist))); 0b; ()]
       ^

q)?[`t; enlist(any;(enlist,(each; {(=;x;0)};colist))); 0b; ()]
'type
  [0]  ?[`t; enlist(any;(enlist,(each; {(=;x;0)};colist))); 0b; ()]
       ^

q)?[`t; enlist(any;(enlist,("k){x'y}"; {(=;x;0)};`colist))); 0b; ()]
'type
  [0]  ?[`t; enlist(any;(enlist,("k){x'y}"; {(=;x;0)};`colist))); 0b; ()]
       ^

q)?[`t; enlist(any;(enlist,("k){x'y}"; {(=;x;0)};colist))); 0b; ()]
'type
  [0]  ?[`t; enlist(any;(enlist,("k){x'y}"; {(=;x;0)};colist))); 0b; ()]
       ^


Why does the value version of the functional select require the non-symbolic version of colist, whereas the eval version does?
How does one include the k version of each k){x'y} in the eval version of the functional select?
Is there a way to get the functional query to work whic doesn't require value or eval ?



eval/value differences have been answered in your other question:
k) portion of parse tree of user defined function
You don't need the k version. Use each.
You don't need eval or value to create the functional select.

To take a qsql query and convert to a functional select we can use parse to help:
q)parse"select from t where any {x=0} each (a;b;c)"
?
`t
,,(max$["b"];(k){x'y};{x=0};(enlist;`a;`b;`c)))
0b
()

See:

Docs: https://code.kx.com/q/basics/funsql/
Whitepaper: https://code.kx.com/q/wp/parse-trees/

The working query here is:
q)?[`t;enlist (any;(each;{x=0};enlist,colist));0b;()]
e a b c
-------
1 0 1 1
2 0 2 2
3 1 0 3
4 2 0 4
5 3 3 0

= can operate on the matrix so you can simplify the query:
q)parse"select from t where any 0=(a;b;c)"
?
`t
,,(max$["b"];(=;0;(enlist;`a;`b;`c)))
0b
()
q)?[`t;enlist (any;(=;0;enlist,colist));0b;()]
e a b c
-------
1 0 1 1
2 0 2 2
3 1 0 3
4 2 0 4
5 3 3 0

